# UIButton above two UIView is not pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have two UIViews. On second "UIView" I have one UIButton, but it must be over the both views.
When I click lower middle UIButton - event is fire, but when I click above the middle - nothing works.

How to fix it?

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdiah.png)

Answer (score 1):

move the button outside of both views and center it vertically

Answer (score 0):

You should create a subclass of `UIView` for `UIView2` and override `hitTest` like this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    if (!self.clipsToBounds && !self.hidden && self.alpha > 0) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
            CGPoint subPoint = [subview convertPoint:point fromView:self];
            UIView *result = [subview hitTest:subPoint withEvent:event];
            if (result != nil) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```